# Postgres query return nothing where there should be a valid data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that should return some rows, but it returns blank. As far as I know .. the pictures down will show the issue.

Here is the query

```
SELECT * from matches m WHERE M.PLAYED_AT BETWEEN (M.PLAYED_AT - M.STARTED_PREDICTION) AND (M.PLAYED_AT - M.ENDED_PREDICTION)
```

This is the table :

```
-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE matches (
    id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at timestamp with time zone,
    started_prediction interval NOT NULL DEFAULT '48:00:00'::interval,
    ended_prediction interval NOT NULL DEFAULT '02:00:00'::interval,
    played_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX matches_pkey ON matches(id int4_ops);
```

[image: the query]

[image: The table data]

I tested the calculation and it worked a lone .

```
SELECT id, (M.PLAYED_AT - M.STARTED_PREDICTION) started , (M.PLAYED_AT - M.ENDED_PREDICTION) ended from matches m;
```

[image: test the calculation Only and it works]

Comment: I think that your between statement is incorrect. You can't just calculate datetime and hours like that (played_at-started_prediction)

Comment: In Postgres you could subtract an interval from a timestamp.

Comment: Ah OK, Didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Ok thanx i will edit the post .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition cannot be right because you are comparing M.PLAYED_AT to be
`BETWEEN M.PLAYED_AT - X AND M.PLAYED_AT - Y` - this can never be because you are comparing a timestamp with a previous timestamp and another previous timestampt.

Probably you meant to do `BETWEEN ... AND (M.PLAYED_AT + M.ENDED_PREDICTION)`

Comment: I do not think so ..

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it should be ***now()*** instead of *played_At* .

```
SELECT * from matches m WHERE NOW() BETWEEN (M.PLAYED_AT - M.STARTED_PREDICTION) AND (M.PLAYED_AT - M.ENDED_PREDICTION)
```